# how to send recived data in string to oncreate method is android?

Tags: android, arraylist

i use aysctask for getting the data from web service. i want whatever data i get from a string,that data add to the  ArrayList markerPoints  arraylist. that is declared at the oncreate so how i add the data to the arraylist.pls help me i am new in android. thanks in advance.

```
           protected void onPostExecute(String response) {


      super.onPostExecute(response);     

          try {

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

            JSONObject jArray = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONObject jstart = jArray.getJSONObject("start");

            JSONObject jend = jArray.getJSONObject("end");

            JSONObject jcureent = jArray.getJSONObject("current");                  

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                startlat=jstart.getString("lat");

                startlong=jstart.getString("long");

                endtlat=jend.getString("lat");

                endlong=jend.getString("long");

                currentlat=jcureent.getString("lat");

                currentlong=jcureent.getString("long");

        }
```

in oncreate I declared the ,
  markerPoints = new ArrayList(); i create the one arraylist, and i want whatever data is get from the json it store into that array.thanks

Comment: What type of arraylist is it ??

Comment: ArrayList<LatLng>  markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); thsi is latlng type of array list. i declared this as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Declare  `ArrayList` as a global variable:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private ArrayList myArrayList;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            ...
            myArrayList = new ArrayList();

            ...
        }
        private final class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
             ...

             protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
                super.onPostExecute(response);     

                try {

                 JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                 JSONObject jArray = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("data");
                 JSONObject jstart = jArray.getJSONObject("start");
                 JSONObject jend = jArray.getJSONObject("end");
                 JSONObject jcureent = jArray.getJSONObject("current"); 

                 for (...  ) {
                    myArrayList.add(jstart.getString("lat"));
                     myArrayList.add(jstart.getString("long"));
                     myArrayList.add(jend.getString("lat"));
                     myArrayList.add(jend.getString("long"));
                     myArrayList.add(jcureent.getString("lat"));
                     myArrayList.add(jcureent.getString("long"));

                  } 
                } catch(...) { }

     }
```

Comment: 1. i create the array list as a global variable. the array list is of latlng type i.e ArrayList<LatLng>  markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();   2. actually i want whatever information get from the json i.e lat and lng is added to the this arrylist. the array list is latlng type.how? thanks.